# How to get the filed data form json file?

Tags: python, json

This code are successful to get the "version" and "shapes" data. (for i in data.get("shapes"):)
but when i swtch "shapes" to  the "label" ,the problme come

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Thanks help.

```
{
  "version": "4.5.7",
  "flags": {},
  "shapes": [
  {
    "label": "2",
    "points": [
      [
        602.8,
        590.2
      ],
      [
        610.3,
        642.0
      ]
    ]
  }
],
"imagePath": "ladybug_13451176_20200410_141545_ColorProcessed_000497_Cam0_20059_026-2678.png",
"imageWidth": 1024
}


import json
import jsonpath
import io


with open("B123.json", mode="r") as dict: 
  data = json.load(dict)
  for i in data.get("shapes"):
    print(i,end="")
```

Comment: Share the contents of `B123.json`. Most likely it doesn't have `"shapes"` defined in it. Or do you mean you renamed `"shapes"` to `"label"`?

Answer (score 0):

`data` is of type [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Calling [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) would either return the value (if present) or `None` (if not present).

So if your data varies and might have no defined `"shapes"`, don't just iterate over it as you could be iterating on a `None` object. So replace this:

```
for i in data.get("shapes"):
```

Instead, put a check first.

```
if "shapes" in data:
    for i in data.get("shapes"):
```

Or better yet maximize the `or` operation which continues to the next if the previous has a false value.

```
for i in data.get("shapes") or []:
```

Comment: so i use the code you privd and show the "{'label': '2', 'points': [[602.8, 590.2], [610.3, 642.0]]}" 
 if i just want show the "label " value . how ? thanks again

Comment: Please check the code again. Here, we just printed `shapes` explicitly. If you are seeing `label`, `points`, and everything else, then you might have just added code that wasn't in your original question. Update the question and let's see what issues you are still facing.

Answer (score 0):

Because "shape" is a list of dict, you cabiterate it. But label is inside shapes dict, you can't just replace "shapes" by "label", also when you will have obtained the contents of label, you still won't be able to iterate it because the value of key label is not a list or dict